# R: Create preferred date format

Tags: r, date

I have a dataframe with a column that stores dates in various ways. All in numbers or with month names instead of numbers, some rows have months / days missing:

```
Group   Date
1       14-7-2017
2       10-sep-2011
3       29-jul-2009
4       2016
5       dec-2018
6       NA
```

The date column in the example above is in as.character format.

I would like my preferred output to look like this:

```
Group   Date
1       2017-7-14
2       2011-09-10
3       2009-07-29
4       2016-XX-XX
5       2018-12-XX
6       NA
```

The format turn to Y-MM-DD and missing months / days will be filled in with XX. The NAs in the date column can remain NA or be changed to XX-XX-XX, doesn't really matter for my purpose.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `lubridate`. So long as you have a set of possible formats:

```
library(lubridate)
parse_date_time(df$Date,c('dmy','y','my'))
#[1] "2017-07-14 UTC" "2011-09-10 UTC" "2009-07-29 UTC" "2016-01-01 UTC" "2018-12-01 UTC" NA
```

Comment: I tried your function and it returns a nice list of dates, but how can I apply these new dates to my dataframe?

Comment: @KakSchoen you can just assign it to the corresponding column: `df$Date <- parse_date_time(df$Date,c('dmy','y','my'))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `anytime::anydate` here. However, you might need to add some formats which it does not identify automatically.  For example, without adding any formats

```
anytime::anydate(df$Date)
#[1] NA           "2011-09-10" "2009-07-29" "2016-01-01" NA           NA
```

Let us add the formats which are missing

```
anytime::addFormats(c('%b-%Y', '%d-%m-%Y', "%Y"))
anytime::anydate(df$Date)
#[1] "2017-07-14" "2011-09-10" "2009-07-29" "2016-01-01" "2018-12-01" NA
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Group = 1:6, Date = structure(c(2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 
5L, NA), .Label = c("10-sep-2011", "14-7-2017", "2016", "29-jul-2009", 
"dec-2018"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```